# Generating alert in file downloading

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1

I am using the following code in JSP to download a file from the server.

JSP Code:

```
<bean:write name="ab" property="status" /> <!-- returns the status (Available/notAvailable) -->

<a href="<%=url%>/ABC/download.jsp?Path=<%=filePath%>&fileName=${CustomerRegistrationForm.vendorId}_certificate.pdf" style="text-decoration:none">Click Here</a>
```

Downloads the file from the server upon clicking on the link (if the file is not present then also it downloads, of course in corrupted format). It works fine if the file is present.

I want to make the file available for download if the status is available and display an alert message if the file is not available.
I tried using `<logic:match>` tag, but I can't make it out.
I am using struts framework.
I also tried writing a javascript function, but that too not working. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the `status` as a `boolean` i.e. `true` for available and `false` otherwise.

Than what you can do is the following:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${status}">
        <a href="<%=url%>/ABC/download.jsp?Path=<%=filePath%>&fileName=${CustomerRegistrationForm.vendorId}_certificate.pdf" style="text-decoration:none">Click Here</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <a href="javascript: alert('File is not available');" style="text-decoration:none">Click Here</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

If the `status` is a `String` then just change this logic: `<c:when test="${status eq 'Available'}">`.